# Interact with program from site (like iTunes)

Tags: c#, .net, url, itunes

There are iTunes links that will open up and app or an album in iTunes from a link in a web browser.

How does this work and can I do it in a C# .NET app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iTunes registers the `itms://` URI protocol in the registry and associates it with iTunes.exe.
The webpage then opens an `itms://` link.

MSDN [documents this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx), including a C# example.